# Bootstrap tag "col-md-8" not centenring

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is that the 3rd row and the 4th don't center!

```
<!--|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 imagemFundo">
<!--|---------------------------------------ROWS-------------------------------------------------|-->
            <div id="1" class="row rowPrincipal ">
                <div class="container" >
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 colPrincipal2 borderRow">
                        <!-----------------------------PANEL-------------------------------------|-->
                                        <div class="panel panel-default panelTop">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">Primeiro Título</div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                Conteúdo do painel.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                <h1 class="panel-title">Segundo Título</h1>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                Conteúdo do painel.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                        <!-----------------------------PANELEND----------------------------------|-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--SEGUNDA ROW-----------------------------------------------------------------|-->
                <div id="2" class="1 row rowSecundario ">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 colSecundario2 borderRow">
                            <p style="color: white" class="text-center titles">SEGUNDA ROW</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--TERCEIRA ROW-----------------------------------------------------------------|-->
```

The problem starts here!!!!!I have tried every single thing and nothing works. I got a hint that may be divs not closed well but i can't find any error :/ I'm a beginner so maybe that's the problem.

```
                <div id="3" class=" row rowSecundario ">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 colSecundario2 borderRow">
                            <p style="color: white" class="text-center titles">TERCEIRA ROW</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--QUARTA ROW----------------------------------------------------------------|-->
                <div id="4"  class="row rowSecundario ">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 colSecundario2 borderRow">
                            <p style="color: white" class="text-center titles">QUARTA ROW</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--FINAL ROW-----------------------------------------------------------------|-->
            </div>
<!--|---------------------------------------ROWS END------------------------------------------|-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me!! I really can't figure it out by myself...

Comment: Could you post your CSS please?

Comment: By the way, you do not need to add empty div's to center. Just offset the div.

Comment: Post a fiddle with more code otherwise we will not know where things are going wrong. What you posted so far is working, so it is hard to tell where to look at for errors.

Comment: @StephenPoley i can't. It is too big. :/

Comment: @DavidDomain offset wasn't working. And it does not work fine. The third and 4th row go to the left and the 1st and 2nd are fine in the middle.

Comment: @DavidDomain how do I post the whole code?
This tells me that there is too much code.

Comment: As DavidDomain says, we can't really work out the problem without more information. But why not remove the apparently superfluous "col-md-2" divs and put a text-align: center on your paragraphs? I would rather expect your class text-center to have a text-align: center, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Nothing about text. 
My problem is that my boxes(col) are not in the center and thats what i want.

Comment: @StephenPoley i can't put my code here it's huge for the preview thing.

Comment: start by commenting out all your non bootstrap classes

Comment: Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demo your code

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="4" class="row rowSecundario ">
  <div class="col-md-8 offset-2 colSecundario2 borderRow">
    <p style="color: white" class="text-center titles">QUARTA ROW</p>
  </div>
</div>
```